# angular 5 function keeps calling on hover

Tags: javascript, angular

I have started working on a simple SPA in angular 5, but now i am stuck in point where function **getFullPathUrl()** is called every time i **hover** card. Function **getFullPathUrl()** gets something like **'test.jpg'** and dimensions and return **www.test.com/156x0/test/test.jpg**. It is suppose to set img src only at the initialization right ? or correct my if i am wrong. Now if i hover any of my cards function is called 40 times and when my mouse leave from card it is called again so many times.

```
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of galleries;let i = index;" [routerLink]="['/'+item.path]"
         (mouseenter)=" setBackground(item.image.fullpath)"
         (mouseover)="showCount = true" (mouseleave)="showCount = false">
        <img class="card-img-top"
             [src]="getFullPathUrl(item?.image?.fullpath,156)" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title imagesCount"></h4>
            <h4 class="card-title title">{{item.name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have a function call on your template. This means on every change detection that function will be called. Since mouse events trigger change detection that’s why you’re having that behaviour. What you need to do is set the return of that function on a property on the component and then just have a variable on your template.

**Edit**

Considering your case scenario you would have something like

```
[src]="rootPath + ‘156x0/test’ + item?.image”
```

Where `rootPath` would be a variable that you would have on your component. Something like

```
rootPath: string = “www.test.com/“
```

This obviously doesn’t look the prettiest in terms of solution but I’m just explaining what you would have to do to break the existing function call into a variable. And your path composition seems a bit tricky so that’s why you need that odd string concatenation.

Comment: So instead of returning value i add it into this.fullpath for example, but anyway i need to call this function to set this image right ? how ? and where should i place that function to get image for every card? PS: i forgot to say i am new to angular

Comment: I have edited my answer for you particular case scenario. You can also consider simplifying the full path or organize it in a different way so that you can read it from the component and then just append the image path at the end.

Comment: [src]="item?.image?.fullpath ? path + '156x0/' + item?.image?.fullpath : defaultImage"  works, thank u for coming here

Comment: Always glad to help :). Please don’t forget to mark the answer as checked so it can help others with similar problem